# Just installed CouchDB, permission error

Tags: permissions, couchdb

Just installed CouchDB 1.2.0 via apt-get. I want access to the error logs in /var/log/couchdb however I can't open the folder, recieving the error message:

```
The folder contents could not be displayed.
You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "couchdb".
```

Owner is listed in the folder properties as: "couchdb - CouchDB Administrator".

What do I need to do to get access?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error this morning and corrected it by:
Adding my user to the couchdb group.  It did require a reboot in order to allow access to /var/lib/couchdb

I used gnome-system-tools to access the groups

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```